# shell script to extract tar file please help

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, extract, tar

I have created a shell script (.sh) to extract a tar file. Below is the code:

```
tar -xvwf 1.0.1.tar
```

But when the script runs and start to extracting the tar, it asks confirmation in each file extract.

```
extract `1.0.1'?
```

How can I avoid that in my script?  I'm running on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `tar xvf 1.0.1.tar` should do the trick; the `-w` options means "ask for confirmation for every action" (`tar(1)`).

Answer (score 2):

Remove the **-w** option, which specifically asks it to confirm on every file.  From the tar man page:

```
 -w, --interactive, --confirmation
       ask for confirmation for every action
```